# Python: Add multiple search filter options to a list like eBay or eCommerce

Tags: python, sql, search, flask, orm

I want to query my database and thereby return results based on various search parameters. Take for example what **eBay** does; you can select multiple colors, multiple categories. 
How do I achieve this?

Say my URL is like this:

*{URL}/search?filter.group[]=doctors&filter.group[]=nurses&filter.type[]=new&query=Heart*

**Pseudocode:**

```
SELECT from post 
WHERE group==doctors OR group==nurses 
AND type==new
```

...

Comment: what orm do you use?

Comment: SQLAlchemy, Flask-SQLAlchemy to be specific